# How to update all primary keys in the existing database

Tags: mysql, multi-master-replication, tungsten-replicator

I'm moving mysql multi-master replication to production using tungsten. I had setup the auto increment and offset values in my.cnf file. To achieve this i'll have to update my all primary keys of all databases to auto increment. Had any one done this? Can some one help me out to do? Current i have 4 databases and i needs to update all primary keys with auto increment.

Thanks,
Swaroop

Comment: You may get better answers over at dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks, I'll move this there